# Cannot verify my download ver20.04.01

Tags: windows-10, gnupg, sha256, sha256sum

I have followed the tutorial steps, which by the way it is very annoying no one mentions the need to type sudo before everything, and when I get to the steps requiring the download of the SHA256 files, I can only download the .gpg file, the other just opens up. but it doesnt matter because when i run the next step and use the line

```
gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
```

it comes back saying

```
~$ sudo gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg: can't open 'SHA256SUMS.gpg': No such file or directory
gpg: verify signatures failed: No such file or directory
```

Help please, my attempts to install ubuntu have only been a disaster so far and i cannot understand why it is being so difficult.

Answer (score 1):

[Is this](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#5-verify-the-sha256-checksum) the tutorial you're following? The error you included suggests SHA256SUMS.gpg isn't there.  Do you have both files, SHA256SUMS.gpg and SHA256SUMS, in your current directory?  I would make sure both files are there and look like this:

```
$ ls -l SHA*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 userid userid 204 Feb 11 14:07 SHA256SUMS
-rw-rw-r-- 1 userid userid 833 Feb 11 14:07 SHA256SUMS.gpg
```